# How should I provide additional information about an exception?

Tags: c#, exceptions

Everytime I need to provide additional information about an exception I wonder which way is actually the *right* way of doing this.

---

For the sake of this question I wrote an example. Let's assume there is a class where we want to update the `Abbreviation` property. From the SOLID point of view it might not be perfect but even if we passed the *worker-method* via DI with some service the same situation would occur - an exception occurs an there is no context to it. Back to the example...

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

Then there are some instances of the class and a loop where the worker-method is called. It can throw the `StringTooShortException`.

```
var persons =
{
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Fo" },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Barbaz" },
}

public IEnumerable<Person> GenerateAbbreviation(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        try
        {
            person.Abbreviation = GenerateAbbreviation(person.Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ?
        }
    }
    // throw AggregateException...
}

public IEnumerable<string> GenerateAbbreviation(string value)
{
    if (value.Length < 5)
    {
        throw new StringTooShortException(value);
    }

    // generate abbreviation
}
```

---

The quesion is: how to add the `Person` or its `Id` (or anything else)?

---

I know the following three techniques:

---

## 1 - Use the `Data` property

Pros:

- easy to set additional information
- does not require creating even more exceptions
- does not require additional `try/catch`

Cons:

- cannot be easily integrated into the `Message`
- loggers ignore this field and won't dump it
- requires keys and casting becasue values are `object`
- not immutable

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GenerateAbbreviation(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        try
        {
            person.Abbreviation = GenerateAbbreviation(person.Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data["PersonId"] = person.Id;
            // collect ex
        }
    }
    // throw AggregateException...
}
```

## 2 - Use custom properties

Pros:

- similar to the `Data` property but strongly typed
- easier to integrate into the `Message`

Cons:

- requires custom exceptions
- logger will ignore them
- not immutable

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GenerateAbbreviation(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        try
        {
            person.Abbreviation = GenerateAbbreviation(person.Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // not suitable for this exception because 
            // it doesn't have anything in common with the Person
        }
    }
    // throw AggregateException...
}
```

## 3 - Wrap the exception with another exception

Pros:

- `Message` can be formatted in a predictable way
- loggers will dump inner exceptions
- immutable

Cons:

- requires additional `try/catch`
- increses nesting
- increaes the depth of the exeptions

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GenerateAbbreviation(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                person.Abbreviation = GenerateAbbreviation(person.Name);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPersonDataException(person.Id, ex);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // collect ex
        }
    }
    // throw AggregateException...
}
```

---

- Are there any other patterns?
- Are there better patterns?
- Can you suggest best practices for any/all of them?

Comment: Not familiar with exceptions in C# but I would normally expect the Person instance still to be valid when the exception is thrown. Have you tried that?

Comment: @JohnKouraklis this is not what the question is about ;-) It's just an extremely simple example to demonstrate what I mean by additional information. If I posted here an entire framework where mutliple methods can throw exceptions and mutliple levels of context information should be provided no one probably would read this and I had a really hard time to explain it.

Comment: @JohnKouraklis I've just made it up for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @t3chb0t I think you've answered your own question here. Consider moving 1, 2, & 3 into an answer and adjusting your question so it's not asking me to pick a style based on my opinion.

Comment: What's wrong with custom exceptions? Done properly, they're part of your domain language and help achieve abstraction away from the implementation details.

Comment: `Data` looks nice to me. First time I hear about it. (As an aside: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278958/6559)

Comment: I have been waiting over a decade to see a .NET application actually provide information in the Data dictionary.  I am still waiting . . . I guess nobody logs it, so no one expects it to get read, so nobody writes in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Data` [FTW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_the_win).

Your "contra":

- "cannot be easily integrated into the Message"

-> For *your* exception types, it should be easy enough to override `Message`so that it *does* incorporate `Data` .. although I only would consider this if the [`Data` is the message](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278958/6559).

- "loggers ignore this field and won't dump it"

Googling for Nlog as an example [yields](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-layout-renderer):

> #### Exception layout renderer
>
> (...)
>
> *format* - Format of the output. Must be a comma-separated list of exception properties: `Message`, `Type`, `ShortType`, `ToString`,
>   `Method`, `StackTrace` & **`Data`**. This parameter value is
>   case-insensitive. Default: `message`

So it seems that's easily configurable.

- requires keys and casting because values are object

Huh? Just dump the objects in there and make sure they have a usable `ToString()` method.

Also, I don't quite see any problem with the keys. Just use some mild uniqueness and you're good.

---

Disclaimer: This is what I could immediately see from the question and what I googled up on `Data` in 15 minutes. I thought it's mildly helpful, so I put it out as an answer, but I have never used `Data` myself, so it might well be that the questioner here knows way more about this than me.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that there are only two things about an exception that are useful, its name and message. Everything else is just useless noise that can and should be ignored because it's simply too fragile rely on it.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you throw Exceptions?  To have them caught and handled.

How does the catching code work out *how* to handle the Exception?  Using the properties that you define on the Exception object.

Never use the Message property to identify the exception, nor to provide "information" that any potential handler should rely on.  It's simply too volatile and unreliable.

I've never used the "Data" property before but it sounds overly generic to me.

Unless you create *many* classes of Exception, each of which identifies a *specific* Exceptional case, how do you know *when you catch the Exception* what "Data" represents?  (See preceding comment about "Message").

Comment: I'd say, `Data`is useless for handling, but valuable for logging to avoid `Message` formatting hell.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the exception message should be a static string that doesn't change depending on circumstances. Any information that is useful to have and varies between calls should go into the `Data` dictionary. Loggers are able to handle this as has been mentioned. The rules concerning the exception message are the same as those concerning logging message.

This extension method can be used to easily add data to an exception before throwing:

```csharp
public static Exception AddData(this Exception ex, string key, object value)
{
  ex.Data.Add(key, value);
  return ex;
}
```

i.e.

```csharp
throw new CustomException("Failed").AddData("key", val);
```

Answer (score -1):

I like your third example, however there is another way it can be coded to eliminate most of your "con"s.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GenerateAbbreviation(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    var exceptions = new List<InvalidPersonDataException>();

    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        try
        {
            person.Abbreviation = GenerateAbbreviation(person.Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(new InvalidPersonDataException(person.Id, ex));
        }
    }

    if (exceptions.Any())
    {
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```